# Button not working only refreshing page

Tags: php, button, submit

Good day! I've been having a trouble with my delete button. I have 3 forms in one page and the two forms are submitting only leaving my delete mo not functioning. I think the problem is with isset but I don't know how will I solve it. Please help.

Here is the code:

```
<h3>Delete Card</h3>    
<div class="formdel">
<form action="" method="post" id="formdel" name="formdel">
<div class="control-group">
<label class="control-label" for="cnum">Card Type Name</label>
<div class="controls">
<select name = "cnum" id = "cnum" style="width: 250px;">
<option value = "NONE" disabled selected>Card Type Name</option>
<?php
$querya = "SELECT CardTypeID, CardTypeName FROM cardtype";
$resulta = mysql_query($querya);


while($rowmem = mysql_fetch_array($resulta)){
echo "<option value = ". $rowmem['CardTypeID'] .">" . $rowmem['CardTypeName'] . "   </option>";
}

?>
</select>

</div>
</div>      

<button type='submit' class='btn btn-large btn-danger' name="delete1" id="delete1" style="margin-left:90px; margin-top: 20px;">Delete</button>                              


<?php

if (isset($_POST['delete1'])){

$canum = $_POST['cnum'];

$querydel = mysql_query("DELETE FROM CardType WHERE CardTypeID = $canum",$connect);

if ($querydel){

echo "<div class='alert alert-success' style='font-size: 12px; width: 300px;'>

<a class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&#215;</a>

<center>Delete successful!</center></div>";
}
else {

echo "<div class='alert alert-success' style='font-size: 12px; width: 300px;'>


<a class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&#215;</a>

<center>Delete unsuccessful!</center></div>";
}
}

?>
```

Comment: Your <form action=""> is nothing.. Not sure if that's a problem but, you never know..

Comment: @Dieter: If the `<form>` action is blank it means the `<form>` posts the data to the same page.

Comment: I could see no errors up to the code you posted. But you didn't closed the form.

Answer (score 0):

Try `!empty` or `$_POST['delete1'] != ""` instead of isset since `delete1` would be already set on `$_POST` variable when the form is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

According to [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp):

> Note: If you use the `<button>` element in an HTML form, different
>   browsers may submit different values. Use `<input>` to create buttons in
>   an HTML form.

If you rely on the button element for passing a value you'll get different results depending on the browser. Instead of `<button>` use:

```
<input type='submit' class='btn btn-large btn-danger' name="delete1" id="delete1" style="margin-left:90px; margin-top: 20px;" value="Delete" />
```

Or you could just include a value attribute in the `<button>` element see http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_value.asp:

```
<button type='submit' class='btn btn-large btn-danger' name="delete1" id="delete1" style="margin-left:90px; margin-top: 20px;" value="delete">Delete</button>
```

In [PHP doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) for `isset()`, it says "Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL." With no value attribute `$_POST['delete1']` is NULL.

Answer (score 0):

There are following errors in your code:

1) You haven't closed your form with `'

2) Please correct the code of delete button.

From

```
<button type='submit' class='btn btn-large btn-danger' name="delete1" id="delete1" style="margin-left:90px; margin-top: 20px;">Delete</button>
```

To:

```
<input type='submit' value="Delete" class='btn btn-large btn-danger' name="delete1" id="delete1" style="margin-left:90px; margin-top: 20px;"/>
```

And then try if this works for you.